# Clone repos from Gitolite in one action

Tags: python, git, ssh, gitolite

Here is my attempt to simplify a process of preparing working environment. Assume your team has many Gitolite hosted repositories and you want to:

- get full list of them;
- clone some of them as simple and fast as can.

This script allows it. So, the answers for above questions are:

Show gitolite repos:

```
ssh git@server_ip
```

And the following code for cloning:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys
import os
import re

FILTER = None

# check shell arguments
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    FILTER = sys.argv[1]

GIT_PATH = "git@server_ip"

# run system command and retrieve result
p = subprocess.Popen("ssh " + GIT_PATH, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()

output = re.sub(r'^[\S\s]*?(?=web/)', '', output)
output = re.sub(r'R|W', '', output)

output = output.split()


# filter function
def f(line):
    if line.find(FILTER) != -1:
         return True

    return False


if FILTER:
    output = filter(f, output)

yes = 'yes'
no = 'no'

for line in output:
    print(line)
    choice = input("Do you want to clone this repo (yes/no): ")

    if choice == yes:
        os.system("git clone " + GIT_PATH + ':/' + line.strip())
        print('Done!')

print('All work is done! Congrats!')
```

Syntax: **python clone.py [filter]**
Filter, when specified, allows to get only repos that contain filter string as substring.

Suggestions for improvement are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an actual, specific question here?

Comment: No, actually I intended to share some useful snippet with others and possibly to get some advices.

Comment: please edit this to match the stackoverflow format, with your question as a question and your answer as an answer.  As with spelling and grammar, getting the form right is a matter of not throwing speedbumps at people who do a lot.

Comment: When writing scripts, there's always a decision: do I do it in shell script, or use a higher level language. A higher level language is useful if you end up creating complex datastructures or even just associative arrays. But if you're mostly just doing a bunch of `os.system()` calls, perhaps you should have used a shell script. Since you have no clear question, here's my suggest for improvement (both overall and perhaps improving your skills): rewrite this in 5 lines of bash.